# Mac ports passing argument to install of ImageMagick

Tags: macos, macports

I am trying to pass the argument `--with-rsvg` when installing ImageMagick with MacPorts.

I am doing it like this:

```
sudo port install ImageMagick --with-rsvg
```

But after installing, I get this error: `"Error: Port --with-rsvg not found"`

I have tried to understand the [documentation](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/graphics/ImageMagick/Portfile) on how to pass that argument, but I fail to see what they mean by this:

```
variant rsvg description {Support SVG using librsvg} {
        depends_lib-append      port:librsvg
        configure.args-replace  --without-rsvg --with-rsvg
    }
```

So my question is pretty simple. How do I install ImageMagick with rsvg support using MacPorts?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer myself.

The command is:

```
port install imagemagick +rsvg
```